# Eclipse Not recognizing Environment Variable (Mac OS Lion, Eclipse Juno 64-BIT)

Tags: eclipse, osx-lion, cocos2d-x

I need some help with trying to setup C++/Java build using Eclipse. I am following this tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started) but just can't understand why I keep getting "please define NDK_ROOT".

I updated the create-android-project.sh file and applied this cmd in Terminal: export NDK_ROOT="same path to NDK as in create-android-project.sh file". When I ran the 'create-android-project.sh', I had no problem with creating the project, Running the newly created project's build_native.sh also ran with any issues.

So after following the steps to update 'Build Command' from default to whatever the tutorial is asking should compile the C++ and Java files in the project, without having to run the build_native.sh in terminal and the project in Eclipse.

If I remove the custom build to default all compiles and runs on the project on both the emulator and device.

I've attached a screenshot of the settings and Console log of the project build.

Dev Environment:
Mac OS 10.8 (Lion)
Eclipse Juno 64-BIT
Cocos2d-x v2.0-x-2.0.3
NDK: android-ndk-r7-crystax-5.beta2

Please advise.[image]

Answer (score 5):

I solved the issue by adding the NDK_ROOT variable to ADT > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Build Variables.

[image]

Hope it helps someone, I know I've been looking for a solution for quite some time.

Comment: That did not work for me but it was close. I had to define the variable 2 level lower in the Environment node so in ADT -> Preferences -> C/C++->Build -> Environment

Comment: I had the same issue with eclipse and solved it by defining NDK_ROOT under eclipse-> Preference -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment

Answer (score 1):

This error is not related to **eclipse**. It tell that the **NDK_ROOT is not define in build_native.sh** file. I solve the issue by adding NDK_ROOT at the top of the build_native.sh file

**build_native.sh**

```
NDK_ROOT="path of your ndk "
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you noly need to set it in C/C++ build-> Environment.

Just like this. It works for me eventually.

Refer to this picture for configuration

[image: Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

In the Left side pane of your eclipse , As I can read that Resources,Android ..etc

In that go in Android, there will be one option to set NDK path

Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK -> set path to the NDK

It is same as you do it for android SDK , here you have to specify NDK path ...

EDITED:

If you still face the problem ...then it is the same problem which I faced while setting it up for my windows version

there is an issue with android ndk version for export NDK_Path .... You may try with crystax ndk version for android it will work for sure

Any more help please feel free to ask

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've tried adding path to the NDK in the project settings but had no luck. The settings location you mentioned is no longer available after an Android project is converted to a C++ project. I cheated and went inside the build_native.sh file and hard coded the path to the NDK. The script is working now and is compiling all C++ files inside Eclipse. What threw me off is that export NDK_ROOT="path to NDK" should have worked, since it is an environment variable.

Comment: @badboy11 : What you doing is not cheating in a way because the problem you are facing is problem of android-ndk ...if you want to try out this export NDK thing it will work with crystax ndk version because in the normal ndk version appear some errors...